# Sierpinski Carpets

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, fractal

Who doesn't love a good fractal? The [Sierpinski Carpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet) is a classic example of a fractal.

To complete this task, you will be required to generate a carpet of type \$n\$ and print the resulting image to the `stdout` (see example below for formatting) \$n\$, representing the level carpet. Steps can be found on this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet) article.

This value will be taken from `stdin` or equivalent.

For example, an input of 4 would produce a level 4 carpet:

```
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■
■   ■       ■   ■ ■   ■       ■   ■ ■   ■       ■   ■
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■                   ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■                   ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■                   ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■                   ■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■
■   ■       ■   ■                   ■   ■       ■   ■
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■                   ■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■                   ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■                   ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■                   ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■
■   ■       ■   ■ ■   ■       ■   ■ ■   ■       ■   ■
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
```

An input of 3 would produce a level 3 carpet:

```
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■
■   ■       ■   ■
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
```

An input of 2 would produce a level 2 carpet:

```
■ ■ ■
■   ■ 
■ ■ ■
```

And a input of 1 would produce a level 1 carpet (just a square):

```
■
```

Note the spaces between the columns.

The idea is to use the ■ character for blocks and space for gaps

The line starts with the ■ character.

As always, the smallest solution wins by character count (due to non-standard characters).

Alternatively, # can be used instead of the ■ character in languages that do not support Unicode.

Comment: Isn't the first example a third level instead of second ?

Comment: Nice question, but do they have to be those characters? those aren't ASCII, which rules out a lot of languages. Can they be just space and X or O? I actually think your image would look better with spaces instead of empty squares.

Comment: Changed sponge to carpets, thanks.

Comment: What if your language does not support unicode output, is there also an ASCII alternative?

Comment: @steveverrill Good idea, I'll specify # and spaces as an alternative.

Comment: Okay, I've specified a ASCII alternative as #, and replaced the white square with a space.

Comment: @steveverrill Good catch, added level 3.

Comment: Can the lines have trailing spaces?

Answer (score 16):

### CJam, <s>38</s> <s>37</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 28 characters

Oh well, we're counting by characters, so let's do some Unicode unpacking:

```
"B胷맋풽巓뱖ᮨ㣙¬䙧੥墱륋청"2G#b129b:c~
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) Just put the desired level into the input field.

#### Explanation

After base conversion, this is

```
3li(#,{3b1f&2b}%_f{f{&S9632c?S}N}
```

which is the same as the following, just with the Unicode character written as `9632c`:

```
3li(#,{3b1f&2b}%_f{f{&S'■?S}N}
```

This code is based on the following observation: if we look at the coordinates *(x,y)* of each cell, then we get an empty cell, whenever both *x* and *y* have a `1` at the same position in their base-3 representation. If you think about it, the small-scale repeating pattern is the significant base-3 digit, then the next more significant digit governs the next larger-scale repetition and so on.

```
3                                      "Push a 3 on the stack.";
 li(                                   "Read input, convert to integer, decrement.";
    #                                  "Raise to that power. This yields the dimensions.";
     ,                                 "Turn into a range array.";
      {       }%                       "Map the block onto the array.";
       3b                              "Convert to base 3.";
         1f&                           "Bit-wise AND each digit with 1.";
            2b                         "Convert to base 2.";
                _                      "Duplicate this list.";
                 f{          }         "Map this block onto one list, with the second list
                                        as an additional parameter.";
                   f{      }           "Map this block onto the second list, with the first
                                        list's current element as an additional parameter.";
                                       "I.e. this iterates over all coordinate pairs.";
                     &                 "Bitwise AND to check that the base-3 representations
                                        had a 1 in the same position.";
                      S'■?             "Select the right character.";
                          S            "Push a space.";
                            N          "Push a newline";
```

The contents of the resulting array are printed automatically.

Thanks to Dennis for shaving off three bytes.

Comment: `#0<'■S` -> `#~S'■` saves 1 character.

Comment: You can replace `[1_]a#~` with `3Yba&`.

Comment: @Dennis neat. thank you!

Comment: @Dennis I keep forgetting that `&` produces a truthy/falsy value (or even that it exists). Might be worth a post in the CJam tips for the canonical way to test whether an array contains some element.

Comment: Man, also post more insights on the base conversions and tricks to it :)

Comment: Should save two chars: `3li(#,{3b1f&4b}%_f{f{&S9632c?S}N}`

Comment: @Dennis Thanks! The `f{f{...}}` is a really nice idea. :)

Comment: Doesn't the Unicode trick use _more_ characters in this case?

Comment: @Ypnypn Nope. It looks longer but that's because the Unicode characters aren't monospaces. The unpacked code has 30 characters.

Answer (score 7):

## Matlab <strike>(113)(110)(99)</strike>(85)

You can try it [here](http://lavica.fesb.hr/octave/octave-on-line_en.php) (You'll have to replace `input('')` with your desired input.)

Now 99 thanks to feersum! And now down to 85 thanks to RTL!

Golfed:

```
a=ones(3);a(5)=0;c=1;for i=2:input('');c=kron(c,a);end;disp(char(kron(c,[1,0])*3+32))
```

Ungolfed:

```
a=ones(3);a(5)=0;c=1;  %creating the template / anchor
for i=2:input('');
    c=kron(c,a);       %recursive iterations
end;
disp(char(kron(c,[1,0])*3+32))
```

```
d=[c,c]*0;  %this is all just for adding the additional spaces
d(:,1:2:end)=c;
disp(char(d*3+32));    %converting to spaces (32) and # (35)
```

Explanation:

I am abusing the kronecker product for this task. (It is a special product defined for two each arbitrary sized matrices. Example:

```
A = [1,2] is a 3x2 matrix, B is a nxm matrix.
    [3,4]
    [5,6]
```

Then

```
kron(A,B) = [1*B , 2*B] is a 2n x 2m matrix.
            [3*B , 4*B]
            [5*B , 6*B]
```

So heres an example for n=5 (In the old counting method it's 4);

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
#   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
# # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # 
#   #       #   #                   #   #       #   # #   #       #   #                   #   #       #   # #   #       #   #                   #   #       #   # 
# # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
#   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                                                       #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                                                       # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
#   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   #                                                       #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                                                       # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                                                       #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   #                                                       #   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
# # #       # # #                   # # #       # # #                                                       # # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # 
#   #       #   #                   #   #       #   #                                                       #   #       #   #                   #   #       #   # 
# # #       # # #                   # # #       # # #                                                       # # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   #                                                       #   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                                                       #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                                                       # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
#   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   #                                                       #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                                                       # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                                                       #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                                                       # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
#   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
# # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # 
#   #       #   #                   #   #       #   # #   #       #   #                   #   #       #   # #   #       #   #                   #   #       #   # 
# # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # # # #       # # #                   # # #       # # # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   #                   #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                   # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
#   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # #   #       #   # 
# # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # # # #       # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # #   # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that the requirements changed. I also updated the code (I just had to change the starting value of the for loop.)

Comment: Instead of `d=zeros(size([c,c]))` you should use `d=[c c]*0`.

Comment: nice, a suggestion: the variable `d` can be avoided by abusing `kron` once more: `disp(char(kron(c,[1,0])*3+32));`,

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, <s>114</s> 108

```
s 1=["# "]
s n=k j++k(map(>>" ")j)++k j where j=s$n-1;k i=j%i%j
(%)=zipWith(++)
main=interact$unlines.s.read
```

Answer (score 6):

## Perl 5: 68 characters

*n* on stdin.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
//,print map/2/?"  ":"■ ",map$_+$',@,for@,=grep!/[24-9]/,0..3x<>/10
```

A decimal coded ternary representation of the list of coordinates is first generated in `@,` (name chosen so there is no need for space between `@,` and `for`) using digits 0, 1, and 3. Now adding x and y coordinates in the decimal domain will have a 2 in the result if and only if there were two ones at matching positions. `//` is used to propagate the default variable `$_` from the outer loop (`for`) to the postmatch variable `$'` when it is shadowed by the default `map` variable in the inner loop.

Answer (score 5):

## Python – 100

```python
r=range(3**~-input())
for i in r:print" ".join("# "[any(i/3**k%3==j/3**k%3==1for k in r)]for j in r)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Racket <s>230</s> <s>229</s> <s>225</s> 220

Not Racket's finest hour for golfing.

Golfed:

```
(define(s n)(letrec([t(λ(x y)(if(or(= x 0)(= y 0))"■"(if(=(modulo x 3)(modulo y 3)1)" "(t(floor(/ x 3))(floor(/ y 3))))))][i(expt 3(- n 1))])(for-each displayln(for/list([r i])(string-join(for/list([c i])(t r c))" ")))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (s n)
  (letrec ([t (λ (x y)
                (if (or (= x 0) (= y 0)) 
                    "■"
                    (if (= (modulo x 3) (modulo y 3) 1)
                        " "
                        (t (floor (/ x 3)) (floor (/ y 3))))))]
           [i (expt 3 (- n 1))])
    (for-each displayln 
              (for/list ([r i])
                (string-join 
                 (for/list ([c i]) 
                   (t r c)) " ")))))
```

Answer (score 4):

## C: <strike>123 118 111</strike> 104 characters

Based on a similar idea as my perl solution.
After adding some spaces:

```
m=0x55555555;
x;
main(n){
  scanf("%d",&n);
  n=1<<2*--n;
  for(x=n*n;x--;)
    printf(x&x/2&m?"":"%c%c",x&x/n&m?32:35,x&n-1?32:10);
}
```

Uses ternary system coding each digit with 2 bits. Illegal values (having two ones in odd-even position) are filtered with `x & (x>>1) & 0b01010101`. Both coordinates are stored in one value, so checking the pixel color is down to `x & (x >> 2 * n) & 0b01010101`. `n` is stored as a power of 2 for convenience.

### Edit

Replaced `define` with a simple constant `m`.

### Edit 2

`0x5555555` mask can be represented with `(1LL<<32)/3`, but we only need `n` of those bits so `n/3` is sufficient.

```
x;
main(n){
  scanf("%d",&n);
  n=1<<2*--n;
  for(x=n*n;x--;)
    printf(x&x/2&n*n/3?"":"%c%c",x&x/n&n/3?32:35,x&n-1?32:10);
}
```

### Edit 3

Minor tweaks. One 2 char gain relying on scanf being executed before the loading value of `n` for the execution of `--n`.
The eol can only follow `#`, duh.

```
x;
main(n){
  n=scanf("%d",&n)<<2*--n;
  for(x=n*n;x--;)
    x&x/2&n*n/3||printf(x&x/n&n/3?"  ":x&n-1?"# ":"#\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 71 bytes

```
Grid@Nest[ArrayFlatten@ArrayPad[{{0}},1,{{#}}]&,1,#]/.{0->"",1->"■"}&
```

**input**

> 3

**output**

[image]

Comment: I followed you like a total creeper. +1 ;).

Comment: Do you think you can shorten this with [SubstitutionSystem](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubstitutionSystem.html) ?

Answer (score 3):

## HTML/JavaScript, 205 Chars

### [Obfuscatweet](http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/), 205 Chars

```
document.write(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

### HTML/JS, 298 Chars

Due to how HTML plays with whitespace, a few characters had to be dedicated to the nbsp char. In addition, the default font of most browsers is not Courier, so I had to set it to that, too. About 20 characters worth of styling. If this requires a direct input method, I can add it, but changing the input currently is setting n to a different value.

[Demo](http://c99.nl/f/114334.html)

```
<script>s='&nbsp;';n=4;m=Math.pow(3,n-1);for(i=0;i<m;i++,d('<br>')){for(j=0;j<m;)if(c(i,j++))d('#');else d(s)}function c(x,y){while(x||y){if(x%3==1&&y%3==1)return 0;x=f(x);y=f(y)}return 1}function f(a){return Math.floor(a/3)}function d(a){document.write(s+a)}</script><style>*{font-family:"Courier"
```

### Readable HTML/JS

```
<script>
    s='&nbsp;';
    n=4;
    m=Math.pow(3,n-1);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++,d('<br>')){
        for(j=0;j<m;)
            if(c(i,j++))
                d('#');
            else d(s)
    }
    function c(x,y){
        while(x||y){
            if(x%3==1&&y%3==1)
                return 0;
            x=f(x);
            y=f(y)
        }
        return 1
    }
    function f(a){
        return Math.floor(a/3)
    }
    function d(a){
        document.write(s+a)
        }
</script>
<style>
*{font-family:"Courier"
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>38</s> <s>35</s> <s>32</s> 31 characters

```
"■ ""՛ୗ䁎뽔휼ꆩ闳⾿➺⥧槲㩡郊"6e4b128b:c~
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Example run

```
$ cjam <(echo '"■ ""՛ୗ䁎뽔휼ꆩ闳⾿➺⥧槲㩡郊"6e4b128b:c~') <<< 3; echo
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ 
■   ■       ■   ■ 
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
```

#### How it works

```
"՛ୗ䁎뽔휼ꆩ闳⾿➺⥧槲㩡郊"6e4b128b:c~
```

converts the Unicode string from base 60,000 (`6e4b`) to base 128 (`128b`), casts to Character (`:c`) and evaluates the resulting string (`~`).

As a result, the following code gets executed:

```
"■ "                                " C := '■ '                                           ";
    li(                             " J := int(input()) - 1                               ";
       {                      }*    " for I in range(J):                                  ";
        z]A*                        "   T := [zip(C)] * 10                                ";
            ):,                     "   U := pop(T)                                       ";
               Sf*                  "   V := [ ' ' * len(u) : u ∊ U ]                     ";
                  4\t               "   U[4] := V                                         ";
                     3/{:+z~}%      "   C := { c : c ∊ zip(concat(u)), u ∊ U.split(3) }   ";
                              zN*  " print '\n'.join(zip(C))                              ";
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3 – <del>116</del> 113 characters

**EDIT:** Well, used the trick I don't like too much myself and compressed the code by 3 bytes. Dunno if that's the best possible way, but I'll go with it.

```python
exec(bytes('ⱴ㵬❛離₠崧氬浡摢⁡㩺癥污稨✫⁫潦⁲⁫湩琠❝਩潦⁲⁩湩爠湡敧椨瑮椨灮瑵⤨⴩⤱爺瀬氽✨㍛✪Ⱙ⡬嬢⭫‧✠⠪⨳椪⬩⤢琻爽瀫爫昊牯椠椠⁮㩴牰湩⡴⥩','utf-16')[2:].decode('utf-8'))
```

It may contain some unprintable characters, so here's a printable version of the string.

```python
'ⱴ㵬❛離₠崧氬浡摢\u2061㩺癥污稨✫\u206b潦\u2072\u206b湩琠❝\u0a29潦\u2072\u2069湩爠湡敧椨瑮椨灮瑵⤨\u2d29⤱爺瀬氽✨㍛✪Ⱙ⡬嬢\u2b6b‧✠⠪⨳椪⬩⤢琻爽瀫爫昊牯椠椠\u206e㩴牰湩⡴⥩'
```

Not too great, but at least beats some languages.

What it expands to:

```python
t=['■ ']
for i in range(int(input())-1):r,p=[k*3for k in t],[k+'  '*(3**i)+k for k in t];t=r+p+r
for i in t:print(i)
```

Somewhat ungolfed in case someone can't see how it works:

```python
t=['■ ']                                     # iteration 1
for i in range(int(input()) - 1):            # do n-1 more iterations
    r = [k * 3 for k in t]                   # first & last rows are the last carpet x3
    p = [k + '  ' * (3 ** i) + k for k in t] # middle row: last carpet, space, last carpet
    t = r + p + r                            # and put them to the new carpet
for i in t:                                  # print final iteration
    print(i)
```

Comment: Wow python, that's impressive

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 76 characters

```
3ri(#:M_*,{_M/:I\M%:J;;{I3%1=J3%1=&0X?:X;I3/:I0>J3/:J0>|}gX'■S?1:X;}%M/Sf*N*
```

This is a direct translation of the formula given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet)

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 2):

## C - 154

Input from stdin. I tried to find a good way to avoid an extra function, but couldn't come up with any.

The character count includes only necessary spaces.

```c
p(l,x,y){
    return l?x/l&y/l&1||p(l/3,x%l,y%l):0;
}
x,y;
main(v){
    scanf("%d",&v);
    v=pow(3,--v);
    for(;y<v;y++,puts(""))
        for(x=0;x<v;)
            printf("%c ",p(v,x++,y)?32:35);
}
```

Comment: [143 bytes](https://tio.run/##DczRCoMgFIDhV5EzDM9Q2mhXifQs4WYEZmLlkurV57z4rn74tRi0ztkzy3ee8AifdQuO2G6vbZWK53mWWDd8p5YnarF9yCvJqR8di3iYObB0V0lF5ecva3gUatG9MwzoG3gVEWUSQiYay2hbFwaA6MPoVsM8i2VZ1BE7IARauBFAeeX8@mlj@2HJwk5/ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Bash+coreutils, 105 unicode characters

Since we're counting characters and not bytes:

```
eval `iconv -tunicode<<<潦⡲眨㌽⨪␨ⴱ⤱琬〽琻眼眪琻⬫⤩笻戠ꂖ昻牯⠨㵸╴ⱷ㵹⽴㭷㹸簰祼〾砻㴯ⰳ⽹㌽⤩笻⠠砨㌥ㄭ籼╹ⴳ⤱簩扼尽簠硼〽紻瀻楲瑮⁦␢⁢㬢⠨╴⵷⭷⤱簩敼档㭯੽|cut -b3-`
```

---

In its decoded form:

## Pure Bash, 143 bytes

```
for((w=3**($1-1),t=0;t<w*w;t++));{
b=■
for((x=t%w,y=t/w;x>0||y>0;x/=3,y/=3));{
((x%3-1||y%3-1))||b=\ ||x=0
}
printf "$b "
((t%w-w+1))||echo
}
```

Input is taken from command-line args:

#### Output:

```
$ ./sierpinskicarpet.sh 3
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ 
■   ■       ■   ■ 
■ ■ ■       ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■   ■ ■   ■ ■   ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## oK, <s>40</s> 45 bytes

```
`0:" "/'" #"{(x-1)(,'//3 3#111101111b*9#,)/1}
```

[Try it online.](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%20%600%3A%22%20%22%2F%27%22%20%23%22%7B%28x-1%29%28%2C%27%2F%2F3%203%23111101111b%2a9%23%2C%29%2F1%7D4%3B)

It starts with `1`, and then draws it in a grid `(1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1)`, which it then draws in a grid the same way, etc. repeated the necessary number of times.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! It should meet the spec now (at the cost of 5 more bytes).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 91 bytes

```python
r=input()-1
for i in range(3**r):x,s='# ','  ';exec"x+=[x,s][i%3%2]+x;s*=3;i/=3;"*r;print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBDkUwEADQvVNMiJQiQq00PYlYiPR/sxnNqGScvmze4oUnHieNKbFDCnes6m7IficDAhLwRn9fGa25nqW9nCpAtQpAWS9@z6Vxy9frgqUpx7URe2lnLPYfuWYbGCmCpDS9)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
’3*Ḷb3ḂḄ&þ`¬ị⁾# G
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//4oCZMyrhuLZiM@G4guG4hCbDvmDCrOG7i@KBviMgR////zQ)**

#### How?

```
’3*Ḷb3ḂḄ&þ`¬ị⁾# G - Link: integer, n
’                 - decrement -> n-1
 3*               - three raised to (that)
   Ḷ              - lowered range -> [0,1,...,3^(n-1)-1]
    b3            - convert to base three (vectorises)
      Ḃ           - least significant bit (vectorises) -> i.e. make 2 trits become 0s
       Ḅ          - convert from base two (vectorises)
          `       - use that as both arguments of:
         þ        -   outer product with:
        &         -     bitwise AND
           ¬      - logical NOT (vectorises)
            ị     - index into:
             ⁾#   -   list of characters ['#', ' ']
                G - format as a grid
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 77 characters

```hs
f n|a<-mapM(:[0,1])[2..n]=[do x<-a;"■ "!!(0^product(zipWith(+)x y)):" "|y<-a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hrybRRjc3scBXwyraQMcwVjPaSE8vL9Y2OiVfocJGN9Fa6dG0BQpKiooaBnEFRfkppcklGlWZBeGZJRka2poVCpWamlZKCko1lUC1sf9zEzPzbEGmKRSUlgSXFPnkKagopCmY/AcA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 194 characters

The `n` received as first argument in command line.

```
<?php
function d(&$a,$n,$e,$x,$y){if(--$n)for(;$i<9;)$p=pow(3,$n)|d($a,$n,$e|$i==4,$x+$p*$j,$y+$p*($i-$j)/3)|$j=++$i%3;else$a[$x][$y]=$e?" ":■;}@d($a,$argv[1]);foreach($a as$s)echo join($s),"
";
```

### Readable

```
<?php

function draw(&$array, $n, $empty, $x, $y) {
    $n--;
    if ($n != 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
            $j = $i % 3;
            $p = pow(3, $n);
            draw($array, $n, $empty || $i == 4, $x + $p * $j, $y + $p * ($i - $j) / 3);
        }
    } else {
        $array[$x][$y] = $empty ? " " : "#";
    }
}

$array = array();
draw($array, $argv[1], false, 0, 0);
foreach ($array as $line) {
    echo join($line), "\n";
}
```

Comment: If you use the char `■` instead of `#`, you can save 2 chars by removing the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

**Scala 230 characters**

Golfed code:

```
object T extends App {def m=math.pow(3,args(0).toInt-1).toInt-1;def p=print _;val x=0 to m;x.map{n=>x.map{j=>if(q(n,j)==1)p(" #");else p("  ")};p("\n");};def q(n:Int,j:Int):Int={if(n>0|j>0)if((n%3&j%3)==1)0 else q(n/3,j/3)else 1}}
```

Ungolfed code:

```
object T extends App {
  def m = math.pow(3, args(0).toInt - 1).toInt - 1;

  def p = print _;
  val x = 0 to m;
  x.map { n => x.map { j => if (q(n, j) == 1) p(" #"); else p("  ")}; p("\n");};

  def q(n: Int, j: Int): Int = {
    if (n > 0 | j > 0) if ((n % 3 & j % 3) == 1) 0 else q(n / 3, j / 3) else 1
  }
}
```

Only necessary spaces are included.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
 ■¹.H{³³┼┼≥: ■@ŗ;┼┼⁴++}{@∑P
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTIwJXUyNUEwJUI5LkglN0IlQjMlQjMldTI1M0MldTI1M0MldTIyNjUlM0ElMjAldTI1QTBAJXUwMTU3JTNCJXUyNTNDJXUyNTNDJXUyMDc0KyslN0QlN0JAJXUyMjExUA__,inputs=NA__)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 162 bytes

```cs
n=>{var f="";int s=(int)Math.Pow(3,n),z=0;while(z<s*s){int x=z%s,y=z/s,h=1;for(;x>0|y>0;y/=3,x/=3)if(y%3==1&x%3==1)h=0;f+=" #"[h]+(z++%s<s-1?" ":"\n");}return f;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY@5TsQwFEXr8VdYRkE2ySxRqHAcCiQqRhqJggIoLGMTS8FBfs5MFvLtwcPSvFu8o6t7FKxV6/XSgXXv@HGAoD84Uo0EwIcJQZDBKnzfOVVaFzIIPnIVNl6qIBss8OJENR2lx0YQwiODQdAYbC9DvTm0J1pkjmWj2PFTbRtNxxKugE1nshdjAtkgxi1ktci5aT3lfbX7GqodH7aiyPp4mDV0SAoh8sv@J1gdy0wqCL4gz/VrSsc0TaCEdX5LMLkhL44wPnsdOu@w4fPC0b/IsbVveC@towxNaHXeraT/1CGa/DnRa8bR6q510DZ68@Rt0A/WafrLxd@M5uUb)

#### Degolfed

```cs
n=>{
    var f="";
    int s=(int)Math.Pow(3,n),z=0;

    while(z<s*s)
    {
        int x=z%s, y=z/s, h=1;
        for(; x>0 | y>0; y/=3, x/=3)
            if(y%3==1 & x%3==1)
                h=0;

        f += " #"[h] + (z++%s<s-1? " " : "\n");
    }

    return f;
}
```

Comment: [156 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY/LTsMwEEXX9VdYRkU2MW2q7OpOukBiRaVKLFgUFpZxiKXgII9T8iDfHlIem7nS3KPRHIO3pg52atD5N/rYYbTviphKI9LjQDDq6Ay9b7zZOR8lxjBzOS2CNlFXFOjkIR/OOtACGFNFHfjMUYRLiIOO5epYf/JMeiF7SGUrO1mqfoc3qIoEGL1ip/Il4UnSLzFP94yyLXv2TIjLqRbmreygX6MsYaPaPP3q8lR1a8hkOw9RQrfMADbX7U/s022pgo1N8LRQ46TIv8K5dq/0oJ3nggxkcfnY6PBh4@zwZ8MzocjirvZYV3b1FFy0D85b/svN3UjG6Rs "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 17 characters

```
■；╷［⌐ ＋２×；┌∔∔；３＊＋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNUEwJXVGRjFCJXUyNTc3JXVGRjNCJXUyMzEwJTIwJXVGRjBCJXVGRjEyJUQ3JXVGRjFCJXUyNTBDJXUyMjE0JXUyMjE0JXVGRjFCJXVGRjEzJXVGRjBBJXVGRjBC,i=Mw__)

-1: *Used `［` instead of `｛` to delete the first `；` inside the loop.*
+1: *Fixed errenous behavior: `■` now corresponds to level 1, as specified in the original post.*

Comment: It *is* competing, per a newer consensus.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer oh, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: And yes, in this case the score *is* 17, but we count solutions in bytes, not characters (Canvas has a code page).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer normally yes, but *this* challenge uses characters, due to `■` being multibyte. Says so toward the bottom in the original post.

Comment: You need to add one to all your inputs. 1 should return a square (i.e. what 0 returns here)

Comment: @PaulClavier ah, ok, it's been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>50</s> 49 bytes

thanks @DLosc for reminding me I should output spaces between the columns

thanks @coltim for -1 byte

```
1@"\n"/("# "1_,/1,'+/')'a*/:\:a:+2!!1_(. 0:"")#3;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/9/QQSkmT0lfQ0lZQckwXkffUEddW19dUz1RS98qxirRSttIUdEwXkNPwcBKSUlT2dj6/38TAA)

Comment: @DLosc thanks, fixed other strange requirements too: stdin/stdout instead of arg/result; off-by-one "level"

Comment: I think you can [drop a byte](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/9/QQSkmT0lfQ0lZQckwXkffUEddW19dUz1RS98qxirRSttIUdEwXkNPwcBKSUlT2dj6/38TAA) by using `("# "1_,/1,'+/')'` instead of `"# "1_',/'1,''+/''`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-S`, 30 characters

```
"■■ "@MX{{aTB3R2i}MSg}MC3**a/3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9f6dG0BUCkoOTgG1FdnRjiZBxklFnrG5xe6@tsrKWVqG/8//9/3eD/JgA)

The basic idea: consider a coordinate grid in base 3. The holes in the carpet occur where 1) a trit in the x-coordinate is `1`, and 2) the trit in the same position in the y-coordinate is also `1`.

```
"■■ "@MX{{aTB3R2i}MSg}MC3**a/3
                                i is 0; a is 1st cmdline arg (implicit)
                        3**a/3  Width/height of the carpet
                      MC        Make a coordinate grid that size and map this function
                                to the coordinate pairs:
                    g            Take each [x y] pair
                  MS             Map this function to each coord and add the results:
         {aTB3   }                Convert to base 3
              R2i                 Replace 2's with 0's
                                  E.g. 15 -> 120 -> 100 and 16 -> 121 -> 101
                                 When we add the results, we get [15 16] -> 201
      MX{            }           Take the max of that list (0, 1, or 2)
"■■ "@                           Use that to index into this string (resulting in a space
                                 iff two 1's coincided to make a 2, or ■ otherwise)
                                Print the resulting nested list with each sublist on its
                                own line and space-delimited (implicit, -S flag)
```

Similar solution, same number of characters but -2 bytes: `{2N({aTB3R2i}MSg)?s'■}MC3**a/3`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 19 bytes

```
‛ #3?‹eʁ3τ∷vB:v⋏†İ⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigJsgIzM/4oC5ZcqBM8+E4oi3dkI6duKLj+KAoMSw4oGLIiwiIiwiNCJd)

### How?

```
‛ #3?‹eʁ3τ∷vB:v⋏†İ⁋
    ?‹              # Push input - 1
   3  e             # Push 3 to the power of it
       ʁ            # Get range [0, that)
        3τ          # Convert each to base 3 (ternary)
          ∷         # Modulo each by two to convert twos to zeros
           vB       # Convert each from binary to integers
             :v⋏    # Outer product bitwise AND with itself
                †   # Logical NOT for each
‛ #              İ  # Index each into " #"
                  ⁋ # Join each by spaces, and then join on newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 92 characters

94 bytes with the special character.

```r
write(c(" ","■")[1+Reduce("%x%",rep(list(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,0,1),3,3)),n<-scan()-1),1)],1,3^n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVI1lDSUFJR@nRtAVKmtGG2kGpKaXJqRpKqhWqSjpFqQUaOZnFJRq5iSVFmRVAtYY6EGigY6ipY6xjrKmpk2ejW5ycmKehqQsUMtSMBcoax@Vp/jf8DwA)

Comment: I'm just amazed people are still doing this 4 years later

Comment: @PaulClavier it's a great challenge; you should be proud :)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>35</sup> 50 bytes

```
' #'{~1|:@}.[:,/0,:"1]9&([:,/_3,./\0"+4}(#,:)),:@1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BasJAGITveYohAdfguibaS5cKQaGn0kOxJxUJ8U@zEndld0MNbfrqMdrDwAx8M8ypDwUrsZRg4EggB00F1h9vrz1DxH7@0l@ZdWIr@SzhMkz3z6PxPRwWXMx2STh56sYRl3HMZZb2cfC@EliZKznkljTzuOTWw5Rwpm68MtrBNP7SePFANxW1zBJOjfPwBkeq1VkNtiLk2n2TdShqym3d/hc@3TCdTJU@0lXpLxEEVFQGXOAlK8PJcD/FHIv@Bg)

*+15 thanks to DLosc for pointing out there had to be spaces between columns.*

This was a quick fix to satisfy the spec and could likely be re-golfed further.

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), original answer, cleaner, 35 bytes

```
' #'{~]9&([:,/_3,./\0"+4}(#,:)),:@1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BCwFBHMXv@yleq4zNGMu6mChRTnIQJ6SN/9rRmtHMbEh89bVxePUOv/frXapQsAxjCQaOGLJOR2C2WswrhgZ7ffbDZmsrefeQcNHdxWF78G41uIwiLie9KgqWU4GpeZBDakkzj1tqPUwGZ4rSK6MdTOlvpRc/dJ3Tk1nCpXQe3uBEhbqquuaEVLs7WYdjQaktnv/BxtXquKP0iR5Kn0UQ0DE34AKjSRa267899JFUXw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 27 bytes

```
mJ' ´Ṫȯ!"□ "¬nmḋ†%2mB3ŀ`^3←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9odXNr//9tSicgwrThuarIryEi4pahICLCrG5t4biL4oCgJTJtQjPFgGBeM@KGkP///zU)

Translation of Jonathan Allan's program.

uses the '□' character.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„# 3I<mÝ¨3δвÉJCDδ&Āè»
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205210/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//@KAniMgM0k8bcOdwqgzzrTQssOJSkNEzrQmxIDDqMK7//80) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/iquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC5en8f9QwT1nB2M8m9/DcQyuMz225sOlwp5ezy7ktakcaDq84tPu/zqFt9v8B).

**Explanation:**

```python
    I<                # Push the input-1
   3  m               # Take 3 to the power this input-1
       Ý              # Pop and push a list in the range [0,3**(input-1)]
        ¨             # Remove the last item to lower the range to: [0,3**(input-1))
          δ           # Map over each integer:
         3 в          #  Convert it to a base-3 list
            É         # Check for each trigit if it's odd, converting the 2s to 0s
             J        # Join the inner bit-lists together to strings
              C       # Convert each from a binary-string to an integer
               D      # Using a copy of itself,
                δ     # apply double-vectorized over this list of integer:
                 &    #  Bitwise-AND the integers together
                  Ā   # Check for each integer whether it's NOT 0 (0 if 0; 1 otherwise)
„#                 è  # 0-based index it into the string "# "
                    » # Join each inner list by spaces, and then each string by newlines
                      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```