# Menger Sponge Generator

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, 3d

### **Challenge**

My challenge, is for you to generate a [Menger Sponge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge) based on the `level`/`iteration` given. You need to draw it in `3d`, anyway you can.

**Examples**

*Inputs:* `0, 1, 2, 3`

*Outputs:*

[image: Diagram]

---

### **Background Information**

**What is a Menger Sponge**

> In mathematics, the Menger sponge (also known as the Menger universal curve) is a fractal curve. It is a three-dimensional generalization of the Cantor set and Sierpinski carpet

**Properties**

> See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge#Properties (too long to copy and paste)

**How do I construct the sponge?**

[image: Diagram]

1. > Begin with a cube  (first image).
2. > Divide every face of the cube into 9 squares, like a Rubik's Cube. This will sub-divide the cube into 27 smaller cubes.
3. > Remove the smaller cube in the middle of each face, and remove the smaller cube in the very center of the larger cube, leaving 20 smaller cubes (second image). This is a level-1 Menger sponge (resembling a Void Cube).
4. > Repeat steps 2 and 3 for each of the remaining smaller cubes, and continue to iterate ad infinitum.

> The second iteration gives a level-2 sponge (third image), the third iteration gives a level-3 sponge (fourth image), and so on. The Menger sponge itself is the limit of this process after an infinite number of iterations.

**Credit**

Background info taken from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge) wikipedia page on Menger Sponges.

---

### **Good Luck!**

Remember this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest program wins!

Comment: @HyperNeutrino 3d is now required, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: you shouldn't change the question when  2 of us answered

Comment: @Jenny_mathy I don't have a choice since doing it in 2d is already a question.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen simply because this is no longer a dupe. However, you will need to tighten up the spec to allow us to onow exactly what kind of *3d output* you want

Comment: Since 3D is now required (invalidating existing answers), I think the question is now unclear.  There is a lot you need to specify for 3D including but not limited to viewing angle, projection, lighting, shading.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I'm editing it right now!

Comment: @NoahCristino I think you'd do better to fix this one in the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1)

Comment: I'm so sad this is a dupe :(. I'm already halfway done haha! This seemed like a fun one.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Should I close this, and post in sandbox, or should I just leave it open?

Comment: @carusocomputing It's not now! With 3d it's not a duplicate, I just need to specify the 3d requirements

Comment: @NoahCristino right now its effectively closed (as dup).  Once you're done in the sandbox and have edited this question you may petition to the community (in comments, chat) to reopen.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12867/61877

Comment: @NoahCristino please check out the sandbox man, it's not a dupe anymore, but you need to let this die and work out the kinks! I've actually posted a suggestion on the Meta site due to this question: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12869/resurrection-sandbox

Comment: @carusocomputing I'm working out the kinks here: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12867/61877 But, I don't know what you mean about resurrecting, since I posted it today, and the other challenge is about 2d menger sponges (Sierpinski Carpets)

Comment: @NoahCristino your original question is the duplicate, and you already have 2 answers. Once an answer is posted, the question is "more-or-less" locked.

Answer (score 4):

anyway.. **here is the 3D answer**

## Mathematica, 15 bytes

```
#~MengerMesh~3&
```

new built-in in Mathematica 11.1

**input**

> 3

**output**

[image]

Comment: Can you add a try it link?

Comment: Why don't you just post it on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40104/sierpinski-carpets since your code generates Sierpinski Carpets (2d menger sponges), not Menger Sponges, which my challenge is about.

Comment: I answered the 3D question ,too.Next time just ask "one" question in order to receive one answer

Comment: Why would you ever need a built-in function to do that either then now?

Comment: @NoahCristino Ask that to all 5000 of Mathematica's builtins :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino lol